# R ggplot how to overlay partial graph on the full graph

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Is there a way to overlay partial graph on top of full graph using ggplot? I have one line graph with time span of say 100 days on X axis and need to add second line that only spans last 20 days, with different color; I don't want to plot second line as having zero values for first 80 days - need to only plot it for last 20 days- using different color. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Also, show us what you've tried thus far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use two geoms with different subsets of your data.frame (for simplicity I use the full df and only one subset):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Index = 1:1000, Value = cumsum(rnorm(1000)))
ggplot() + geom_line(data = df, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
           geom_line(data = df[500:700,], aes(x = Index, y = Value), col="red")
```

[image]